# How to disable swipe month in flutter tablecalendar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

i used flutter [TableCalendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) plugin, I want to disable swipe next month option.
my code is

```
              child: TableCalendar(
                headerVisible: false,
                focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
                firstDay: DateTime(1995),
                lastDay: DateTime(2050),
                startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dont need any swap, you just need to set `availableGestures`:

```
availableGestures: AvailableGestures.none,
```

Comment: Yes working, very thanks.